# detect unresolved elements in polymer-polyfilled browser

Tags: polymer, web-component, custom-element

I'm trying to detect if a custom element has been registered yet, e.i if it is still unresolved.

In a browser that supports custom-element (e.g Chrome) I can do that by checking that is it is not an instance of `HTMLUnknowElement` and that it doesn't match the pseudo-class `":unresolved"` with `element.matches` or any vendor-prefixed equivalent.

But when I'm working under polyfill, the `matches/webkitMatchesSelector/mozMatchesSelector` function breaks when called with `":unresolved"`

Is there a way to have a peek on the list of unresolved elements ? Or any other way that would work under polyfilled browser ?

Thanks

**EDIT**

Just found that [doc](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/debugging.html#unregistered-element-bookmarklet) with a [bookmarklette](https://gist.github.com/ebidel/cea24a0c4fdcda8f8af2) that detects any unresolved element on the current page. The problem is it doesn't work on polyfilled browsers.

The reason is that it check if the consctrucor *is still* `HTMLElement` whereas in a polyfilled browser the constructor *is always* `HTMLUnknownElement`

Comment: Its specific, but you could check `element._readied`. That's when `[unresolved]` is removed under the polyfill: https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-dev/blob/09807ace8328476d965d178e6c6852569ba26584/src/instance/base.js#L161

Comment: Thx for the answer. I have another scenario where I want to check if the CustomElement has been registered _before_ creating it. I was thinking of using [getRegisteredPrototype](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-dev/blob/7d422768549b2cb82959dae6ba2868467244e616/src/declaration/polymer.js#L70). What do you think about that @ebidel ?

For the record: I could just create an instance of this element and check _readied but it's an element that start doing a lot of thing as soon as created

Comment: You could check `Polymer.elements`, although I'm not sure if that also includes the list of polymer-element candidates to upgrade.